# How to give each user a free trial period in android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to publish an Android app with 15 days as a trial period and after that, there will be a one-time subscription charge applicable for the lifetime. I see there is an option in play store developer account for the trial period, so my question is if the user cancels the subscription in the trial period after that is that user will able to use the app? I don't want to change any code for this in my .apk file.

Answer (score 4):

In the Developer Console, you can set up a free trial period that lets users try your subscription content before buying it. The trial period runs for the period of time that you set and then automatically converts to a full subscription managed according to the subscription's billing interval and price.

When the trial period ends, Google Play automatically initiates billing against the credit card that the user provided during the initial purchase, at the amount set for the full subscription, and continuing at the subscription interval. If necessary, the user can cancel the subscription at any time during the trial period. In this case, the subscription remains active until the end of the trial period, but Google Play sets the subscription not to renew automatically; at the end of the trial period the subscription expires, and Google Play does not charge the user.

You can set up a trial period for a subscription in the Developer Console, without needing to modify or update your APK. Just locate and edit the subscription in your product list, set a valid number of days for the trial (must be 7 days or longer), and publish. You can change the period any time, although note that Google Play does not apply the change to users who have already "purchased" a trial period for the subscription. Only new subscription purchases will use the updated trial period. You can create one free trial period per subscription product.

For more information, please check the documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Comment: Thanks for your brief answer but if the user cancels in the middle is he able to access my application?

Comment: in 2020 this still a feature and how does it work if say you want to let them use an app for a week or 10 times and then force them to buy it with a one time payment? Possible? does it require coding? what if they uninstall and reinstall on the same phone?  Also, will google ban my app if i have my own mechanism to stop the trail and collect payment through another processor?