# How to give each user a free trial period in app purchase in android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to publish an Android app with 7 days as trial period. Currently I have developed an app but I need some guidance.

I have very little experience and cannot seem to find any useful documentation about implementing a free trial period, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095854/how-to-give-each-user-a-free-trial-period-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-app purchase does not support the case of a trial **directly** because the in-app billing is a simple one-time purchase model. 
Your trial of the full-features, entirely within your own code. Specifically you'll have to figure out how you are going to implement this in such a way that a user cannot simply uninstall and reinstall the app to get a fresh free trial.
This will need some server-side tracking on your end of device.Once the user trial has elapsed, your app will have to lock the full features. Your app should then support a purchase flow through Google in-app that, when completed, permanently unlocks the full features.

For further details visit the link below
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en