# How to give Android App users free trial period for one time app purchase?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development, google-play-console

I would like to make it so my app will have a free trial period for maybe 10 days and then there will be a one time purchase option for the app itself. I saw a few similar questions here:

[How to give each user a free trial period in app purchase in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60053898/how-to-give-each-user-a-free-trial-period-in-app-purchase-in-android)

[How to give each user a free trial period in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095854/how-to-give-each-user-a-free-trial-period-in-android)

However it seems that the recommended approach is to use a subscription not a one time purchase, is there a way to offer a free trial on a one time purchase app? Otherwise it seems that the longest time period in a subscription is a year:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en

If not, and I do have to use a subscription model; how do I change an existing app published on google play console from a one time purchase app to a free trial app with a subscription? 
Note: I used Unity 3D game engine to make the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Non-Consumable IAP and a backend server. When your user open the app it will connect to the server and check users permissions. The server can grant access to the user if the user purchased the app already or is in the trail period.

You can use SaaS like Firebase if you don't want to setup your own server. It makes life much easier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was really hoping there would be an easier way. If I may ask, do you know any tutorials/guides for specifically this approach to publishing an app?

Comment: No problem. Not specifically but I suggest looking into Firebase tutorials. They have plugins for unity and it is quite simple to use. You basically need a database (like firebase database) where you store when your user registered and if the user bought the app. You can then adjust your app look according to information you get from the database.

Comment: You could do it with local data storage but it is easier for your users to cheat.

Comment: Making it cheat proof is a whole other story. You would need to have all your logic and data on the server and use your mobile app just to display it.